# Search for parent of an email - Access parent node of a child - Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app on android studio, I have connected the project to the `Firebase` (Real time database).

I have two types of accounts, business acc and regular acc, when the user logs in, based on his information (`email`, `password`), I want to know which page I want to send him to (the `HomeActivity` for business or for regulars).

So based on the structure of my database, I want to search for the email of a certain user and if I find it, I want to see, if it belongs to `User Business` or `User Regular`.

How can I do that by code in java? Thank you.

**Database Structure :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With your current data structure, you'll need to run a separate query for regular users and for business users to find the node. That is because you can't search across two levels of nodes with a Firebase query. For more on that, see my answers:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

For each node you'll need to do something like:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("User Business").orderByChild("email").equalTo("aamer@company.com")
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```